# Is there a filepath for the highest level, Computer, directory on the mac? (dir above Macintosh HD)

Tags: macos, finder

The filepath for Macintosh HD is simply '/'. A step above is a folder called your-user-name's Macbook (or whichever type of machine you have) that houses the HD, Network, Remote Disc, and any other mounted images. I know there is a keyboard shortcut to this location, but I was wondering if there is a special filepath that I could use to communicate this location to other applications.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be looking for `/Volumes`. Here all network volumes are mounted, as well as CDs/DVDs, DMGs, USB drives, etc.

```
$ ls -l /Volumes
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  1 Nov  6 08:39 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx  0 root  wheel  0 Nov  6 14:06 MobileBackups
```